# Encoding in XML declaration python

Tags: python, xml, encoding, declaration

I have created an XML file using python. But the XML declaration has only version info. How can I include encoding with XML declaration like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Comment: how you are generating XML, which lib?

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import Document
>>> a=Document()
>>> a.toprettyxml(encoding="utf-8")
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n'
```

or

```
>>> a.toxml(encoding="utf-8")
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
```

you can set the encoding for the `document.writexml()` function in the same way.

Comment: How do you actually writexml() and keep the encoding?

Comment: It should be noted that when you pass `'UTF-8'` as the `encoding` argument, `toprettyxml()` returns a `bytes` object. Thus, when you write to a file you must open it with the `'wb'` option `with open("minidom_example.xml", "wb") as f: \n f.write(xml_str)`

Comment: Note that according to the docs, `writexml()` did not get the `encoding`-parameter until Python 3.9. So prior to that you have to use `toxml()`/`toprettyxml()` and then write that string to a file afterwards