# Python is removing encoding in xml declaration when writing to file

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, io, elementtree, pretty-print

I have this code:

```py
    from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
    from xml.dom import minidom
    from io import BytesIO
    [...]
    tree = et.ElementTree(root)
    f = BytesIO()
    tree.write(f, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
    print(f.getvalue())
    xmlstr = minidom.parseString(f.getvalue()).toprettyxml(indent="   ")
    with open("output/Task_Score_Value." + str(sheet.cell(row=line, column=1).value) + ".md", "w+") as file:
        print(xmlstr)
        file.write(xmlstr)
```

I got the following output (I'm only printing the first lines)

```
b'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>\n<CustomMetadata xmlns="http://soap.[...]
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<CustomMetadata xmlns="http://soap.[...]
[...]
```

Why the "encoding=UTF-8" is being removed in the second print (and, of course, also in the file)?

Comment: A solution to my problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597622/encoding-in-xml-declaration-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encoding in XML declaration python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597622/encoding-in-xml-declaration-python)